# Django group by only using users_id and get all other fields from model

Tags: django, select, group-by

**views.py**

```
condition = Q(vendor_id=vendor_id)
sum_invoice_qry = Sum('amount', filter=Q(transaction_type=1))
sum_payment_qry = Sum('amount', filter=Q(transaction_type=2))
qs = Transaction.objects.values('users_id').annotate(sum_invoice=sum_invoice_qry).annotate(sum_payment=sum_payment_qry).filter(condition)
```

=> I need to group by users_id and all other fields from model,
     - But, currently it is making this query:

```
SELECT `tbl_transactions`.`users_id`, SUM(CASE WHEN `tbl_transactions`.`transaction_type` = 1 THEN `tbl_transactions`.`amount` ELSE NULL END) AS `sum_invoice`, SUM(CASE WHEN `tbl_transactions`.`transaction_type` = 2 THEN `tbl_transactions`.`amount` ELSE NULL END) AS `sum_payment` FROM `tbl_transactions` WHERE (`tbl_transactions`.`vendor_id` = 3544 AND `tbl_transactions`.`billing_type` = ) GROUP BY `tbl_transactions`.`users_id`, `tbl_transactions`.`date_time`, `tbl_transactions`.`date_added` ORDER BY `tbl_transactions`.`date_time` DESC, `tbl_transactions`.`date_added` DESC
```

=> Why the date_time and date_added is appended in group by? how to remove them
=> How to get all others fields, like vendor_id, amount... from models

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Transaction(models.Model):
    users = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(),on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vendor_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    #transaction_type = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    TYPE_CHOICES = ((0, 'Select Transaction Type'),(1, 'Invoice'), (2, 'Payment'))
    transaction_type = models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=True,choices=TYPE_CHOICES)   
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15,decimal_places=2)
    out_std_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15,decimal_places=2,blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)    
    attachment = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/transactions/%Y/%m/%d",blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    billing_type = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    date_time =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False)
    added_by = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Transaction, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tbl_transactions'
        ordering = ['-date_time','-date_added']

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.transaction_id
```

Comment: I think you might need to drive from the user model, not the transaction model. See the django cheatsheet for this where it's counting the number of books for a publisher. Django uses the foreign key to make the connection: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet